# Menu toggle not working when routing pages

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have a dashboard. I have a sidenav toggle method and a logout method. When I call sidenav.toggle() method on another page it gives error "Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined". But when I call the logout method it works. Can someone help me?

I have already moved the menu path where the pages are and it didn't work.

Menu html

```
    <mat-toolbar-row>

      <!-- TOP MENU DO SITE -->
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>

      <h2>{{ title.getTitle() }}</h2>

      <span class="spacer"></span>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="onLogout()">
        <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
      </button>

    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Html pages when I call the menu

```
<app-dashboard-header></app-dashboard-header>
```

ts/components

```
    toggle():void
      {
        this.sidenav.toggle();
        console.log(this.sidenav.toggle);
      }
```

Cannot read property 'toggle' of undefined
[code the html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIYEz.png)
[code the menu html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neQ3w.png)

Comment: please provide the  ts/component file where "sidenav"is defined, As you said other pages give error, may be because scope of sidenav is only for the component for which it is developed, Hope this helps.

Comment: where are you setting `sidenav`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot the put the code. toggle():void
      {
        this.sidenav.toggle();
        console.log(this.sidenav.toggle);
      }

Comment: you're still not showing where you're assigning `sidenav`.  Your error is stating that its' undefined.  Where is the code where you're setting up an implementation of that object?

Comment: I don't have this code, I'll look it up.